# maps of independent RVs when there is only pairwise independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know that for independent RVs $X_1, ..., X_n$ and measurable $g$, $h$, you have $g(X_1, ..., X_m)$ and $h(X_{m+1}, ..., X_n)$ are independent.

But if there is only pairwise independence, that $X_i, X_j$ are independent for $i=1,...,m$ and $j={m+1}...n$, then does the conclusion still hold? The proof in my textbook for the former doesn't really translate to this situation.

Comment: No - the usual counterexample works: assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. symmetric Bernoulli and that $X_3=X_1X_2$, and consider $g(x,y)=xy$ and $h(x)=x$.

Comment: @Did But $X_1, X_3$ are not independent.

Comment: Yes they are - just check carefully, for example $P(X_1=X_3=1)=P(X_1=X_2=1)=\frac14$.

Comment: @Did Here are my calculations: $\Pr(X_1=0, X_3=0) = \Pr(X_1=0) = 0.5$, $\Pr(X_1=0)\Pr(X_3=0) = 0.5\cdot 0.75$.

Comment: Nobody is zero here, rather, `symmetric` Bernoulli random variables $X$ are such that $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\frac12$.

Comment: @Did - I've always seen that be called the Rademacher distribution.